# why fade in/out only working once?

Tags: jquery, hover, fade

I know it is a very idiot problem but i'm trying to make a div show and hide on mouseover but when mouse hover the div it only works one time, then the div fadeout and dont fade in again.
Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/rB9fk/3/

Comment: @user1090389: The fact they're not supported at all in any released version of IE would be a good reason to pass on those.

Comment: @Inerdial Please don't mention IE to me, it gets me nervous

Comment: Please don't mention IE to me, it gets me nervous [2] LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fading out doesn't just make an element invisible, it makes it not display at all. After `$(this).fadeOut('fast')` executes, there is no `div.backgroundHover` to hover over in the view.

You should only fade out the same element you're fading in:

```
$(this).find(".botoesHover").fadeOut('fast');
```

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rB9fk/5/

Comment: Thank you! I'm learning Jquery only by myself and the simple things are making me feel like a total stupid. Thank you for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's probably a better solution:

Uses CSS3 transitions, no jQuery necessary.

http://jsfiddle.net/rB9fk/7/